# How can I connect to an existing RDS database using AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless, serverless-framework

I am building a serverless app and want to connect to an existing database. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection to the DB is not something infra-related but functional. So you will have in the code the connection to the DB and call to cursors.

Exception: If you use app-sync for your API with direct calls (not lambda), you can declare the DB and make calls to it directly.

Comment: wow! I have been going about it all wrong then. So this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbclusteridentifier will only be for creating a new instance of an RDS? not making a connection.

Comment: @V.Villacis exactly. CloudFormation is just for creation of the RDS instance